# Coluna Não É Encontrada Com Inner Join

Tags: mysql, laravel

Linhas:

1 - Dados vindo do formulário de filtros 
2 - Esse **with** eu entro em uma função de relacionamento do Model. Eu faço isso porquê preciso ordenar minha lista por ordem da coluna **MEDIA**. 
3 - O estranho é que preciso fazer um INNER JOIN para a mesma tabela porquê senão algumas colunas que quero pegar na QUERY não funciona. Isso que não entendo no Laravel. Sim, sou eu que estou errando, mas não sei aonde. 
4 - Dentro desse JOIN eu busco concessionárias que tenham avaliações e que não tem, conforme escolho no formulário de filtros, por isso faço esse **IF**. 
5 - Depois eu faço o **AVG(RATING)** para trazer a média de classificação que a concessionária tem. 
6 - A função **ORDER_AVG** e a **CLOSURE** estão no **MODEL**. 
7 - No formulário de filtros há a opção do usuário escolher os registros que possuam determinada média (1 a 5). Por isso eu estou usando o **HAVING**. Mas nem funciona, não filtra. Não entendo porquê também.

```
$arrData        = Input::all();

$consulta       = Dealer::with(['order_avg'])
                ->join('dealer_ratings', function($q) use ($arrData){
                    if(array_key_exists('filterByAvaliacao', $arrData)){
                        if($arrData['filterByAvaliacao'] == 1)
                            $q->on('dealer_ratings.id_concessionaria', '=', 'dealers.id');
                        else
                            $q->on('dealer_ratings.id_concessionaria', '<>', 'dealers.id');
                    }
                    else
                        $q->on('dealer_ratings.id_concessionaria', '<>', 'dealers.id');

                    $q->whereNotIn('id_status', [1, 4]);
                })
                ->selectRaw('*, dealers.id, count(dealer_ratings.id) as qtd_avaliacoes, AVG(rating) as media')
                ->groupBy('dealers.id')
                ->orderBy('media', 'desc')
                ->whereIdCidade($arrData['filterByCidade'])
                ->whereIdTipo($arrData['filterByTipo'])
                ->closure(function($query) use ($arrData){
                    if($arrData['filterByMarca'] && $arrData['filterByMarca'] != 0){
                        $query->whereIdMarca($arrData['filterByMarca']);
                    }

                    if($arrData['palavras-chaves'] != ''){
                        $query->where('concessionaria', 'REGEXP', $arrData['palavras-chaves']);
                    }
                })
                ->paginate(10);
```

### MODEL

```
public function scopeClosure($query, \Closure $callback) {
   $callback($query);
   return $query;
}

# Order By Media de Stars
public function order_avg(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\DealerRating', 'id_concessionaria')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(rating) as media')
    ->having('media', '=', Input::get('filterByStars'));
}
```

Resumo:

Eu quero pegar uma lista de concessionária condicionadas por Cidade e Marca. E na mesma consulta trazer a média de classificação e ordenado por ela.

Comment: Qual é o erro que está dando?

Comment: O erro é que o HAVING não funciona. Não dá erro, simplesmente é ignorado... Rsrs

Comment: Também acredito que não precisava daqueles dois JOINS na mesma tabela.

Comment: Existe um erro na sua função `order_avg`. A abordagem correta é fazer isso dentro de um queryScope, como eu ensinei na outra pergunta. Daí você faria `Model::where(...)->orderAvg()->where()->where()->get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `with` do Laravel tem como finalidade, unica e exclusiva, de trazer resultados referentes à relacionamentos.

No contexto que você está usando a função `order_avg`me parece muito mais um **Query Scope** do que uma vontade de **carregar os relacionamentos**.

O Query Scope tem como objetivo adicionar um trecho de uma query, que você vai usar muito, para ser reutilizada.

Por exemplo, se eu preciso fazer um mesmo join complexo para 30 consultas, eu não vou dar CTRL+C no método (até mesmo porque no OOP temos a "reutilização", e reutilização não é CTRL+C + CTRL+V).

Então, para evitar essas 30 consultas repetidas, usa-se Query Scope:

Exemplo:

```
  public function scopeAtivos($query)
  {
     $query->whereNotNull('data_ativacao')
           ->whereStatus(1)
           ->where('nivel_id', '<>', 1);
  }
```

Daí, ao invés de copiar e colar essa query toda vez, é mais inteligente sempre fazer assim:

```
Usuario::ativos()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando utilizamos [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) temos várias formas de codificar e quando eu percebo que o código vai exigir muitas linhas, separo por linhas para que eu possa debugar cada linha.

**Exemplo:**

```
$arrData = Input::all();

$consulta = Dealer::with(['order_avg']);
$consulta = $consulta->join('dealer_ratings', function($q) use ($arrData){
              //code
             });

$consulta = $consulta->selectRaw('*, dealers.id, 
             count(dealer_ratings.id) as qtd_avaliacoes, 
             AVG(rating) as media');
```

E assim por diante na mesma pegada do seu código. Nessa forma eu debugo item a item quando acontece da geração não dar certo. Utilizo também atalhos ([scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)) e não utilizado **where nomeados** (no mundo Laravel é condenado esse tipo de nomenclatura, exemplo `whereId(1)` que é a mesma coisa que `where('id','=',1)`, mesmo isso coexistindo no framework Laravel).

Nesse momento estou mais observando o código, mas, pelo que pude perceber tem erros de lógica de codificação. Como relatado em outra resposta o `with` está sendo utilizando como `join`, mas, são coisas completamente diferentes. No **order_avg** faça um join simples, o resultado vai começar a clarear e utilize a forma que te mostre de linha a linha fazendo um comando por linha retornando para a mesma variável, tendo assim sempre o último Query Builder.

Faça também um debug na sua SQL como descrito e mostrado nesse link: [Debugging Queries in Laravel](https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel):

**Exemplo:**

```
$results = User::where(function($q) use ($request) {
    $q->orWhere('email', 'like', '%john@example.org%');
    $q->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%John%');
    $q->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%Doe%');
})->toSql();
dd($results);
```

Código referente link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel

***Resultado:***

```
select * from `users` where (`email` like ? or `first_name` like ? or `last_name` like
```

Quanto for executado o `dd` ele vai mostrar a SQL pura sendo isso gerado pelo framework.